# JSP code not evaluated in custom tag call

Tags: jsp, escaping, jstl, evaluation, custom-tags

I'm new to JSP and JSTL and am having an issue where code in a `<%= .. %>` block is not being evaluated when it forms only *part* of a custom tag attribute

```
<myForm:text myBean="${myBean}" inputClass="form-class" inputName="pageNumber"
    label="Go to page" size="1"
    onkeypress="javascript:checkKey(<%= formName %>, '<%=listRequestFor%>', <%=recPerPage%>, <%=numPages%>);" 
    onkeydown="javascript:numbersOnly();" 
    onchange="javascript:goToPage(<%=formName%>, '<%=listRequestFor%>', <%=recPerPage%>, <%=numPages%>);" />
```

And this produces HTML something like the following:

```
<label for="" class="">
    Go to page 
</label>

<input type="text" id="" class="form-control" name="pageNumber"
    value="" size="1"     
    onkeypress="javascript:checkKey(&lt;%= formName %&gt;, '&lt;%=listRequestFor%&gt;', &lt;%=recPerPage%&gt;, &lt;%=numPages%&gt;);" 
    onkeydown="javascript:numbersOnly();" 
    onchange="javascript:goToPage(&lt;%=formName%&gt;, '&lt;%=listRequestFor%&gt;', &lt;%=recPerPage%&gt;, &lt;%=numPages%&gt;);">
```

It looks like the `<%= .. %>` tags are being escaped and therefore the JSP expression is not evaluated before the custom tag is evaluated... any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a dirty hack (no less than JSP deserves) I've defined variables which can be evaluated before being passed to the custom tag:

```
<%
String onkeypress = "javascript:checkKey("+formName+", '"+listRequestFor+"', "+recPerPage+", "+numPages+");";
String onchange = "javascript:goToPage("+formName+", '"+listRequestFor+"', "+recPerPage+", "+numPages+");";
%>

<myForm:text myBean="${myBean}" inputClass="form-class" inputName="pageNumber"
    label="Go to page" size="1"
    onkeypress="<%= onkeypress %>" 
    onkeydown="javascript:numbersOnly();" 
    onchange="<%= onchange %>" />
```

This seems to have resolved the issue although it would be nice to understand why/what is going on